# Checking for valid int

Tags: java, android, arrays, exception, bluetooth

I am receiving data from Bluetooth as a byte array, I can turn this into a char array and the data will display correctly if I display it in a `TextView` however when I try to run my function that will iterate through all the spaces in my byte array it gets tripped up when it comes to the `/u0000` (aka NULL?) character the NumberFormatException catches but it crashes after the catch code has run. A typical `byte[]` for me would look something like `{'1','2','\u0000','\u0000'}` and that would represent the number 12 being sent through Bluetooth.

My idea was to have the code check for the int value then catch the exception if it wasn't parseable or  continue to run if it was. This would then set the boolean and the calling function would receive whether the character is a valid int or not.

Here is my code:

```
private boolean checkForInt(char c) {
    boolean isInt;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(c + "");
        isInt = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        isInt = false;
    }
    return isInt;
}
```

Comment: you want to check for spaces from byte array ??

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question is, but the checkForInt can be reduced down by checking the ascii value of the char (eg 'return c >= 48 && c <= 57;'). You could also try trimming the string to see if the '\u0000' are removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Character.isDigit(char) on your char c.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into problems with the NUL-terminator character, when iterating over the byte array check if the i<sup>th</sup> character is NUL, if so don't try to parse it...